# How can I target text in a string and add a span to edit it specifically?

Tags: reactjs, dom, jsx

I have a string thats being dynamically added in React app for a website.

For example
line1:"Hello my name is Larry and I loveeee krabby patties".

How do I target just the name Larry so I can put a span around it to change the color?

what I have tried the obvious,
line1:"Hello my name is Larry and I loveeee krabby patties"... didnt work,
line1:"Hello my name is +  + Larry +  + and I loveeee krabby patties"... didnt work

A lot of variation but they do not work.

then I am adding it in like this.

## {line1}

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following: line1.replace('Larry', 'Larry'). For the  tag to come through in the HTML you will have to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML from React. https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

So the end result would look like this:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={line1.replace('Larry', '<span class="red">Larry</span>')}/>
```